# Shapely Cascaded Union Failure

Tags: shapefile, shapely, mergeshapes

I am trying to merge polygons using shapely. Here is the piece of code that is being used. This code, fully functional earlier, doesn't seem to work (probably because my python packages were updated).

```
#open shapefile
fshp = fiona.open(shpFileWetlandPath)
shapesTotal = []
#create collection of shapes to merge
for counterShp in range(0, len(fshp)):
    shapefile_record = fshp[counterShp]
    shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(shapefile_record['geometry'])
    print("adding shape " + str(counterShp))
    shapesTotal.append(shape)
print("shapes added. attempt union")
shapeMerged = cascaded_union(shapesTotal)
```

This fails with the error message:

```
Assertion failed: (!"should never be reached"), function itemsTree, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 372.
```

I am using shapely 1.5.16 and python 2.7.11.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your operating system and how you updated your python packages? Did you use Conda? Pip? Windows installers?

Comment: I am working on OS X El Capitan. All packages were updated using conda.